# Selecting a point $(X, Y)$ randomly from a triangle. Find $E(X | Y = y)$.

Tags: probability

> A point $(X, Y)$ is selected randomly from the triangle with vertices
>   $(0, 0)$, $(1, 1)$ and $(1, 0)$. Calculate $E(X | Y=y)$.

So firstly I drew the diagram for the triangle. Then:

$$ E(X | Y=y) = \int^1_0 x h(x|y)dx\ $$

where 
$$ \iint f(x,y) = \frac{bh}{2}f(x,y) = 1  \rightarrow f(x,y) = 2 $$

and

$$h(x|y) = \frac{f(x,y) }{f(y)}\ = \frac{2}{\int^1_0 2dy}\ = 1 $$

so

$$ \int^1_0 x h(x|y)dx\ = \int^1_0 x * 1dx =  \frac{1}{2} $$

Is this correct? I have a feeling it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

What is the conditional distribution of $X \mid Y$?  Think geometrically:  if $Y = y_0$, then we can only choose points from the triangle of the form $(x,y_0)$, where $x \in [y_0, 1]$.  So the conditional distribution of $X$ for a given $Y = y_0$ is also uniform, but it is uniform on $[y_0, 1]$.  Now what is the expected value of $X$ given $Y = y_0$?  Clearly, it must be a function of $y_0$.

Note that this intuitive approach only works because the probability distribution inside the triangle is uniform; if it were more complicated, then we would need to do some calculations.

If you want to do it rigorously, then you must be careful with your integration and be explicit about the support of all functions you obtain.  For instance, the density of $X \mid Y$ is $$f_{X \mid Y}(x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)},$$ where $$f_Y(y) = \int_{x = -\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx.$$  But the true specification of the joint density is $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} 2, & 0 \le y \le x \le 1, \\ 0, & {\rm otherwise}. \end{cases}$$  Therefore, when integrating for the marginal density of $Y$, we must restrict the region of integration for $x$ to be over those values where the joint density is nonzero; i.e., $$f_Y(y) = \int_{x=y}^1 2 \, dx = 2(1-y), \quad 0 \le y \le 1.$$  Thus $$f_{X \mid Y}(x) = \frac{1}{1-y}, \quad y \le x \le 1.$$  (Note that here, $y$ is regarded as a fixed constant with respect to the conditional distribution.)  And this is precisely what we found through geometric intuition:  this is the density of a uniform distribution on $x \in [y,1]$.